# script works only after refresh

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

in the first page i have an image with a link that you can click on it:

```
<div style="width: 97px; height: 130px;">
<a href="objects_lost.html?obj=images/dog.png">
<div>
<img src="images/dog.png" alt="" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
<p style="color: black; margin-top: 0px;">DOG</p>
</div>
</a>
</div>
```

and when you click on it, opens a new page that shows the image you clicked. BUT IT ONLY WORKS AFTER ONE REFRESH.

```
    <img src="" id="image"/>        
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function whatImg() {
            var str = getUrlVars()["obj"];
            document.getElementById('image').src = str;
        }

        function getUrlVars() {
            var vars = [], hash;
            var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
            for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
                {
                hash = hashes[i].split('=');
                vars.push(hash[0]);
                vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
                }
            return vars;
            }
        whatImg();
    </script>
```

any help?
I use JQuery Mobile

Comment: You don't seem to be using jQuery...

Comment: I'm not too good with Javascript, but as far as I know, it's parsed from top to bottom. Try switching `getUrlVars` and `whatImg` around and see what that does? Also, why aren't you using a server side scripting language like PHP to supplement your JS? That way, you can simply access `$_GET['obj']` and you won't even need 'getUrlVars' at all.

Comment: I'm newbie :( Can you help with code?

Comment: ok it worked with $(window).on("hashchange",function() {
  whatImg();
});

Comment: Note that having div tags (block elements) inside a tags is only allowed in html5.

Answer (score 3):

If a hash changes, the script will not fire again. You need to add an event listener like:

```
$(window).on("hashchange",function() {
  whatImg();
});
```

Comment: There is no `hashchange` here.  The only reason this works is because `hashchange` fires on load.

Comment: @JeffB jQuery mobile adds a hash in front of any link and loads its content by ajax, thats why this "hashchange" works ;-)

Comment: @godesign You are right.  I forgot he was using jQuery Mobile.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your JavaScript is running before your page finishes loading.  On the refresh, the page loads from your local cache (i.e. much quicker) and your image element is ready before the script runs.  If you run your code from a local server, you may notice that it works on the first try due to the fast loading of the HTML.

The correct fix is to make your code run after load.  In jQuery, you would do this like so:

```
$( function() {
    whatImg();
});
```

This is more or less a standard jQuery shortcut for:

```
$(window).load( function () {
    whatImg();
});
```

It should be noted that the answer that suggests using `hashchange` works because `hashchange` fires on the first page load.  You do not actually have a hash in your URL.  The correct solution is to make your script run after load.

Comment: I totally agree with you that his code needs a document-ready-statement. But in jQuery Mobile its recommend doing it with `pageinit` (http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageinit/). Why the hashtag works in my opinion I mentionned above as a comment.